# How to add new line while editing multiline text in ag grid

Tags: ag-grid

I have my custom-cell-editor which is basically used to edit multi-line text. I am using prime ng text area while editing.

When I press <kbd>enter</kbd> my cell editing gets stopped and the editor gets closed, but I want a behavior where some key combination e.g <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> will give me a new line into that opened text-area box while editing.

I tried by some event in JavaScript, but still that editor is getting closed once I press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>.

Is there any way to stop propagating other ag grid events when my key combination is <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>?

`event.preventDefault` is also not working.

Comment: See [ask], and especially [mcve]. The idea is you describe what you want to do, show what you tried, and tell us what results you get. Reproduce your issue on plunk or stackblitz so that others can help you easily.

Comment: I got the answer  event.stopPropagation ();

Comment: @Komal Kadam Can you please help me out with the solution. I am also running into same issue but unfortunately could not make it happen.

Comment: This is a good question. If we can get some solution to override Shift+Enter with Alt+Enter or both and leave the Enter for only submission, it will help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use Shift + Enter for agLargeTextCellEditor if you are using ag-grid